# Discontinuity at Interface

Tags: pde, finite-difference, finite-volume, diffusion

The equation at the left of the interface is

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial C_i}{\partial t} = D_i \nabla^2 C_i - z_i \frac{D_i}{RT}F \nabla \cdot (C_i \nabla \phi_2)
\end{equation}

The equation at the right of the interface is

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial \epsilon C_i}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \biggl(\epsilon D_i \nabla C_i + z_i \frac{ D_i}{RT}F\epsilon C_i \nabla \phi_2 \biggr) + S(x) 
\end{equation}

with an extra source term accounted for pore wall reaction and precipitation (also an extra dependent variable $\epsilon$ for porosity).

At $t=1e-5$ the concentration for $C_1$ looks like

[image]

At $t=1e-2$ the concentration for $C_1$ looks like

[image]

But since the value of the source term is negative, I suppose it should be a upward parabola at the interface.
From time $t=1e-3$ to $t=1e-2$, the distribution for $\phi_2$ changes dramatically at the left of the interface though.
[image]
[image]

Some concentrations on the other hand are smooth across the domain though, but $C_1$ and $C_8$, which have the two largest initial condition values, are discontinuous like the picture shown at the interface.

After $t=1e-2$ the RADAU5 solver converges very slowly (I guess it won't converge to a meaningful values anyway).
I'm using cell-centered finite volume for it is easier to implement the Neumann boundary conditions. The discontinuous point is at the first cell right at the left of the interface. I'm using $N=100$; for $N=400$ the discontinuous point even show earlier.

What could be the problems? And how should I resolve it?

Thanks!

**Note:**

It's assumed that concentration and potential are continuous at the interface, which in fact they are, but in a **cell-centered grid**, I'm thinking I can't just naively do nothing at the interface.

Comment: [Here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/interface-formulation-at-finite-volume-boundaries-when-using-the-dual-mesh) is an exact same question but without answer. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to post in the comment section and see if he resolve the problem :(

Comment: Where is the interface in your plot? How are you discretizing your problem? (Finite elements? Finite differences? Finite volumes?)

Comment: The interface is between the jump node and the node on its left. I'm using finite volumes with cell-centered grid. I found that I have a discontinuity on the coefficient between the interface, since the flux on the right of the interface gets a multiple of porosity $\epsilon$, while the flux on the left do not. I simply average the coefficient though. (Regarding [this post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/how-should-non-constant-coefficients-be-treated-with-finite-volume-first-order-u)) Also the potential across the interface is non-smooth.

Comment: What mathematical conditions must you enforce at the interface?

Comment: HEY! I found [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/pubs/iim94/iim94.pdf) paper and replace the variable coefficient to harmonic means (which work for discontinuous coefficient as the author said). There's no discontinuity at the interface! Although he mentioned some other technique, but they're too hard for me though. The solution seems to have steep boundary layer (on the concentration) to tackle next though.

Comment: If you have a clear answer - you could write it as answer to your own question so the next guy gets a clear answer.  If everyone did that then you would have had the answer before your first comment.